# how to get a var from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i made a MailInput component :

```js
function MailInput(props) {
  return (
    <div className="mail-input">
      <input
        type="email"
        placeholder="Enter your email"
        className="mail-input"
        onChange={props.redirect}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default MailInput;
```

i called MailInput in this component :

```js
function ProfileBody() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleChangeEmail = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
    console.log(email);
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    CreateUser(email, username, password);
  };

  return (
    <div className="profile-div">
      <ProfileCard img={pdp}/>
      <h1 className="mail-title">Email :</h1>
      <MailInput redirect={() => handleChangeEmail()}/>
      <h1 className="password-title">Mot de passe :</h1>
      <PasswordInput />
      <Button height="50px" width="50px" redirect={() => handleSubmit() } />
      <Insta />
      <Face />
    </div>
  )
}
```

i'm trying to get what's written in the input tag but it didn't work the way i did it. i'm a newbie to react js and javascript in general so i probably missed a bunch of stuff

Comment: what is  `props.redirect` supposed to be/ do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `onChange` prop you are passing a function that does not accept any parameters: `() => handleChangeEmail()` but when you defined the function it it supposed to be called with an event argument: `handleChangeEmail = (e) => {}`.

The prop is also called `onChange` yet you are trying to access it inside the `MailInput` component as `props.redirect` when it should be `props.onChange`.

Comment: you're right i changed it now i have `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')` i think it's because target doesn't exists here